# Could not autowire mongodb repository spring-boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm still new on Spring Boot, i added a document named Article in mongodb database using Spring-Boot, i want to add comments inside that article. But Spring-boot can't autowire my repository in my Application.

Here's my Repository class that implements ArticleRepositoryCustom interface which contains ajouterComment method.

```
public class ArticleRepositoryImp implements ArticleRepositoryCustom {

@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


@Override
public void ajouterComment(String auth,String commentAuth, String text, Date date) {
    Comment comment=new Comment("comentAuth", "auth", date);
    mongoTemplate.save(comment);
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("author").is(auth);
     mongoTemplate.upsert(Query.query(criteria), new Update().push("comments",comment), Article.class);
}

}
```

ArticleRepository

```
public interface ArticleRepository extends MongoRepository<Article, ObjectId>,ArticleRepositoryCustom {
public Article findByAuthor(String author);
}
```

this my SpringBootApplication class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Example2MongoDbApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private ArticleRepository repository;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Example2MongoDbApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {

    repository.save(new Article(UUID.randomUUID(),"Ettaibi",new Date(),"LKITAB2"));
    System.out.println(repository.findByAuthor("med"));
    repository.ajouterComment("Med", "Said", "Hello Med", new Date());  

    }
```

when i run my app i get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'example2MongoDbApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private demo.ArticleRepository demo.Example2MongoDbApplication.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'articleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property ajouterComment found for type void!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at demo.Example2MongoDbApplication.main(Example2MongoDbApplication.java:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private demo.ArticleRepository demo.Example2MongoDbApplication.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'articleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property ajouterComment found for type void!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 15 more
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'articleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property ajouterComment found for type void!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 17 more
```

This is my class Article

```
@Document
public class Article {
@Id
private ObjectId id;

private UUID authorId;
private String author;
private Date date;
private String title;
private byte text;
public List<Comment> comments;



public List<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}
public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}
public ObjectId getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(ObjectId id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public UUID getAuthorId() {
    return authorId;
}
public void setAuthorId(UUID authorId) {
    this.authorId = authorId;
}
public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public byte getText() {
    return text;
}
public void setText(byte text) {
    this.text = text;
}
public Article(UUID authorId, String author, Date date, String title) {
    super();
    this.authorId = authorId;
    this.author = author;
    this.date = date;
    this.title = title;
}

}
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that based on [this documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) and specifically the Configuration section inside 3.3.1 it looks like your custom repository is not being picked up because it ends in Imp instead of Impl.  Here is the relevant text:

> If you use namespace configuration, the repository infrastructure tries to autodetect custom implementations by scanning for classes below the package we found a repository in. These classes need to follow the naming convention of appending the namespace element's attribute repository-impl-postfix to the found repository interface name. This postfix defaults to Impl.

They do mention an XML way to configure the postfix if you wanted to do that.  There is probably a Java configuration or annotation method as well but I do not know that off hand.